# Latest build not visible in App store Connect to submit build for review

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have uploaded Multiple builds form 1 to 13 for app version 3.5.11. I want submit app for review with app version 3.5.11 and build no 12.

But in App store connect, add build section i am able select form 1 to 8 builds only. From 9 to 13 build only not visible.

I have also connected with apple support team but did not get any response.

Please check attached images. In TestFlight section you can see upto 13 no build is visible and in App store connect from 1 to 8 builds.

**TestFlight Image**

[image]

**App Store Connect Image**

[image]

Comment: facing same issue since last few days, already raised ticket to apple support.